# Skaffold testing during development

Tags: node.js, google-kubernetes-engine, skaffold

I am trying to add testing to a Node.js service.

```
# package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watchAll"
  },
```

The problem is if I use `test-watch`, it stops the skaffold pipeline.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta2
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: microservices-quiz-app
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: auth-img
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: src/**/*.js
            dest: .
test:
  - image: auth-img
    context: auth
    custom:
      - command: npm run test-watch # !!!
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - auth/k8s/*.yml
  - ingress-srv.yml
```

`skaffold dev` is stuck after running `test-watch`

```
Testing images...
Running custom test command: "npm run test-watch"

> auth@1.0.0 test-watch
> jest --watchAll

PASS src/tests/app.test.js
  GET /
    √ responds with a default message (69 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.372 s
Ran all test suites.
```

The other problem is when I use Google Cloud Build, I get `npm not found`.

```
Build [auth-img] succeeded
Starting test...
Testing images...
Running custom test command: "npm run test"
sh: 1: npm: not found
Command finished with non-0 exit code.
running tests: command npm run test finished with non-0 exit code: exit status 127. Check the custom command contents: "npm run test".
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

```
steps:
- id: 'Deploy application to cluster'
  name: 'gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - >
    gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone=$_ZONE $_CLUSTER;
    skaffold run -f=skaffold.yaml --default-repo=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID;
```

(Is `npm run test` not run within the created Node container (using `auth-img`)? It would be cumbersome to have to specify the same images in cloudbuild.yaml just to run some tests)

What is the best approach to testing with Skaffold? At first, I had my `tests` folder outside of `src` so that they are not synced and trigger a rebuild, but it's very easy to miss the results without scrolling up.
[image: enlarged terminal]

Answer (score 1):

The test isn't run in a container by default. We can explicitly use docker to create a container with the generated `IMAGE`.

```
test:
  # auth
  - image: auth-img-dev
    context: auth
    custom:
      # run test in container
      - command: echo $IMAGE && docker run -e CI=true $IMAGE npm test
```

However, in Windows we would need to replace `$IMAGE` with `%IMAGE%`, so I think it is better to only use it for continuous integration and run `npm run test-watch` locally in a separate terminal window. (There is probably a way to [connect](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container) with the docker image to not have to reinstall the dependencies locally, but you are probably in charge of one microservice so it isn't much of a hassle.)

I find it simpler to have 2 different Dockerfiles and 2 skaffold configurations.

**skaffold.dev.yaml**

```
# less images to build and no tests
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta2
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: microservices-quiz-app
build:
  artifacts:
    # auth
    - image: auth-img
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: src/**/*
            dest: .
    # quiz
    - image: quiz-img
      context: quiz
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    # react-client
    - image: react-client-img
      context: react-client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: src/**/*
            dest: .
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - auth/k8s/*.yaml
  - quiz/k8s/*.yaml
  - react-client/k8s/*.yaml
  - jwt-secret.yaml
  - ingress-srv.yaml
  - kafka.yaml
```

**skaffold.yaml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta2
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: microservices-quiz-app
build:
  artifacts:
    # auth
    - image: auth-img
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    - image: auth-img-dev
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    # quiz
    - image: quiz-img
      context: quiz
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # react client
    - image: react-client-img
      context: react-client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    - image: react-client-img-dev
      context: react-client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
test:
  # auth
  - image: auth-img-dev
    context: auth
    custom:
      # run test in container
      - command: echo $IMAGE && docker run -e CI=true $IMAGE npm test
  # react-client
  - image: react-client-img-dev
    context: react-client
    custom:
      # run test in container
      - command: docker run -e CI=true $IMAGE npm test
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - auth/k8s/*.yaml
  - react-client/k8s/*.yaml 
  - quiz/k8s/*.yaml
  # - jwt-secret.yaml created manually
  - ingress-srv.yaml
```

The production `skaffold.yaml` still needs to build the dev images to be able to run tests.

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
# alpine doesn't work with mongodb-memory-server
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --omit=dev

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The production Dockerfile usually is a multi-stage build (not sure for a nodejs server), for example with React:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install --global serve
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
CMD ["serve", "-l", "5173"]
```

With Golang:

```
## Build
FROM golang:1.20-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o /quiz

## Deploy
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10

COPY --from=build /quiz /quiz

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/quiz"]
```

You could also use the dev image as the first stage of the production image.